# Unpickable object - sharing and proxy object creation

Tags: python, proxy, python-multiprocessing, shared-variable

I have a class Inner which cannot be pickled, and a class Outer which holds an instance of Inner which I want to share between processes, via pipe or queue. I was not able to do so because of the Inner class, so I tried creating a proxy object from BaseManager, which I would share instead of Inner.

I tried the following code, but now I get a pickling error when trying to retrieve the proxy object from the manager.

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process, managers.BaseManager

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('Outer', Outer, exposed=['foo'])

class Project:
   def __init__():
      self._manager = MyManager()
      self._manager.start()
      self._queue = Queue()
      self._ready = False

    def validate():
        while True:
            if self._ready:
                outer_manager = self._queue.get()
                break

    def worker():
        outer_proxy = self._manager.Outer() #PicklingError: Can't pickle <class Inner>
        self._queue.put(outer_proxy)
        self._ready = True

def main():
    project = Project()
```

I have seen a few solutions here from which I put together this code, but none of them talked about an error upon creation from the manager.
My end goal is to be able to pass an Outer object from the child process to its parent process.
Any ideas how to go around this?

Note: I cannot make changes to Inner class.